# What makes Emacs a great editor for a Lisp programmer?

Tags: emacs, lisp

Whenever I look into an editor for Lisp, inevitably Emacs comes up first. From the perspective of someone who hasn't looked much at Emacs, what makes it great relative to things like Vim, Eclipse, etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The slime  Emacs mode interact with an "inferior" lisp for a more better lisp experience: Emacs will ask lisp for:

- completion of identifier
- documentation
- testing your new code
- debugging
- inspecting object.

the fact that Emacs was written by lisp hacker make the part specifically written for lisp particularly well tuned.

Answer (score 6):

Emacs is great for Lisp because Emacs is *written* in Lisp (mostly). The people who designed and implemented Emacs wanted an editor that was well suited for writing Lisp code.

Comment: Yes but it seems to me the emacs+lisp combo is almost legendary. Is there really nothing else to it? It doesn't have concrete features that won't exist in other editors?

Comment: I agree with your conclusion if not your reasoning.  Notepad was written in C++ (or whatever); does that make it a good C++ editor?  Also, to nitpick, emacs is written in *emacs-lisp*, which is a dialect not strictly applicable outside of emacs itself.  But still, yeah.  Why would you want anything else?

Comment: ...almost as legendary as the icky dark-corners of elisp... ;-)

Comment: I don't know why I would want emacs, learning it seems like a substantial time investment. So I was wondering why I can't live without it. What is it that makes it so great?

Comment: harpo: C++ was specifically designed so that compiled programs only included the features of the language that are required for that program.  A Lisp program (which hasn't been put through a tree-shaker or such) inherently includes the entire language, including its own compiler.  A better comparison would be a text editor written in Python or Ruby -- and I think that, sure enough, Python editors are relatively more popular for editing Python code.

Answer (score 4):

There are some things that "make Emacs a nice environment for a lisp programmer[/hacker]":

1. The "high-level" parts of emacs are all written in elisp; modules/modes can be edited to suite and the entire elisp environment is "live". The interactions can be *very* complicated, but, if you're a lisp hacker... and can stand elisp...
2. Good modes for *editing* lisp buffers (aka files). This makes sense: create a better mode to make working *on* Emacs nicer to create a better mode to...
3. Various ["inferior"] modes for working with REPLs from other LISP implementations: Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure, etc. (Inferior modes don't end at "LISP dialects".)

Of course, Emacs is a general-purpose text editor -- which just happens to include a kitchen sink and a toaster -- and is suitable even for people who dislike parenthesis (although this may be problematic for creating a truly nice ".emacs" config... if this is indeed the case).

Now, for working on a *Java* project, *I prefer* the Eclipse IDE -- now, if only they could have included a good editor :-/ -- but that's just the nature of the beast...

Try it: you make like it. If not, move on.

Perusing [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/) (and *actually trying the interactive tutorial*) will likely lead to a more enjoyable adventure.

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 for complaining about the Eclipse editor; what rot. A programmer's editor without even a macro facility?! Back in the day the JDE was better than any IDE, but these days... the big 3 Java IDEs are *very* productive.

Answer (score 4):

Watch [Marco Baringer's SLIME tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B_4vhsmRRI).

'nuff said.

Comment: This video is quite old, and tend to give a very complicated explanation on how to set things up. If I never used slime before, I'd be very wary of even trying to get it to work after watching the video.

Answer (score 4):

A bit broader perspective: Emacs is plainly and simply an excellent **programmer's editor**. Lisp programmers tend to be experienced programmers who value greatly their tools.

Yes, Emacs has a steep learning curve and it does not come with training wheels, but Emacs is immensely powerful. A mindboggling power tool in trained hands, bit like Lisp in this sense. Emacs is a programmable editor, and Lisp is a programmable programming language. They go hand in hand :)

Emacs and Lisp go way back together (70's & 80's) with some common big name contributors like Stallman, Steel, Moon, Greenblat, etc. It's easier to see further while standing on the shoulders of giants.

Both Emacs and Lisp have been around for decades, practically on every platform -- and will be in foreseeable future, so investments in learning them will not be lost. Learning one editor **really well** (over the years) does bear fruit.

> "A good craftsman is known by his tools."

(Yes, some of this apply to vi too).

Answer (score 3):

Emacs is a category of text editors. Widely known and used is the GNU Emacs editor and its variants. GNU Emacs is itself almost completely customizable using Emacs Lisp, a dialect of Lisp.

Since GNU Emacs can be programmed in Emacs Lisp, it is easier for Lisp programmers to customize the editor than an editor who would use another extension language.

GNU Emacs has simple ways to control external tools like a Lisp system. For example the shell mode makes it possible to run a Lisp and interact with it in a buffer.

Lisp developers have invested a lot of time to develop more sophisticated extensions to GNU Emacs to control a and interact with an external Lisp.

http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/

In recent years SLIME has seen widespread usage in the Lisp community. It was originally developed for coding in Common Lisp. SLIME provides a lot, mostly text-based, tools which as a sum make a Lisp development environment: editing support, listener for interactive work, backtrace, inspector and more. SLIME supports several Common Lisp implementations and provides a communication between a running Common Lisp system and the editor. This integration of the editor with a running Common Lisp is very extensive in SLIME.

There are other Emacs-like editor with similar capabilities: Hemlock of CMUCL and CCL, The LispWorks editor, Allegro CL's editor and some others. They often provide a more GUI-based approach and not all tools are implemented as editor buffers. All those can also be used with GNU Emacs and SLIME.

Answer (score 1):

What makes Emacs so great (particularly for Lisp development)?

Complete malleability, from within itself.

Being written in a Lisp makes it particularly suitable for editing, transforming, and otherwise diddling other Lisps. This is doable in (essentially) any other editor as well, but it isn't, to the degree Emacs is.

The effort required to write an Eclipse plugin *dwarfs* that of extending Emacs, modulo the e-lisp learning curve (it's... not my favorite Lisp). I *would* say there's a "tipping point" at which implementing "big" functionality in Emacs becomes equally troublesome, but that may be personal bias.

I don't know how easy/hard it is to extend Vi[m].

Answer (score 1):

Emacs' heritage as an editor written by lispers for, er, lisping, is reflected in how s-expressions are a fundamental editable unit -- in other editors, you can move, select and cut by line or word, but in Emacs you can also do those things by s-expressions; there are built-in commands such as `forward-sexp`.

So that's *fundamentally* useful when editing lisp source, but then on top of that there's [paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit), which provides commands for manipulating trees of sexps in an elegant manner that would embarrass refactoring IDEs for other languages. It's hard for me to imagine a serious lisp programmer who wouldn't be vastly more productive once familiar with paredit.

Similar capabilities have, in recent times, been added into other editors, but as more of an afterthought. The Emacs authors have always been writing the lisp parts of Emacs inside Emacs itself, so the lisp-specific capabilities have a certain level of maturity and integration that many of us Emacs users believe give us an edge in terms of productivity.

Answer (score 1):

This question should be a no-brainer. The answer is simple: *Emacs **is** (Emacs) Lisp*.  Emacs is a Lisp environment, and it has been so for a long, long time.  The Lisp machines (all of them) heavily based their Lisp environments on Emacs, for instance.

It is true but incomplete to say only that (GNU) Emacs is *implemented* in Lisp.  Emacs ***is*** (99.999%) Emacs Lisp.  Think of Emacs as Lisp made more interactive and extended to manipulate thingies such as buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Funny enough, I searched the page for the words like "type" "typing" - nobody mentioned that Emacs is all about making typing and navigating the text more comfortable! There isn't anything you cannot do in emacs by using the keyboard only. This may sound like a minor advantage for people used to use mouse when programming. This advantage, clearly isn't the most important, and this isn't something you'll be able to use from the very start as the  commands require that you memorize them. But after a few months you'll see that you can do things much faster then people who use mouse.

Emacs or some of it's modes may not provide as many benefits as other modern IDEs do in the area of intellisense or project management, but when it comes to editing the text of the code, those modern IDEs have yet much to learn :)